# How to display categories listing in product listing page vuestorefront?

Tags: magento2, vue-storefront

I am working on vuestorefront with magento 2.
In vuestorefront I am using **vuetique** theme.

I want to display **category listing** in **layered navigation section** on vuestorefront. Same as magento 2 layered navigation.

Please check below two attached screenshot.

[image]

vuestorefront screenshot

Comment: its just one screenshot :)

Answer (score 2):

The simplest solution is to add categoryIds to defaultFilters section of your config file, if that doesn't work create one custom attribute(must be of type int or keyword in ES) in magento and use that(Add that to defaultFilters instead).